# sharepoint site with codebehind gives me Could not load the assembly, make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page alarm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, code-behind

In a sharepoint site with code behind, when I publish from wsp everything works but if I paste de aspx file directly on my website from the SharePoint designer I get the "Could not load the assembly, make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page alarm".

Do you know why is that?

This is my first line in the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="RPC.SharePoint.Calcula.Default,RPC.SharePoint.Calcula,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=Neutral,PublicKeyToken=613479fcd4366789" %>
```

and this is my class:

```
namespace RPC.SharePoint.Calcula
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

I'm guessing that the codebehind is joining the logic to the aspx so maybe I have a problem in the inherits sentence...

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not allow you to use page with code behind. You have to compile your code to assembly first. Sign your assembly and make it fully trusted by either deploy in GAC or register in your SharePoint web config.

If you deploy your solution in wsp file. The steps above are done automatically. But if you use SharePoint designer, you have to do that step manually.

Comment: Hi, Ok so if I remove the codebehind field the inherits sentence should do the work, but for some reason it isn't doing it, do you see what's wrong in my sentence? how can I get it right?